# convert MySQL tables fin text or pdf file

Tags: mysql

I have one more Query on MYSQL

I need to create files from MySQL Tables 
For example there is MYSQL DB called Customers with table information with following fields
Cust_id, cust_name, cust_phone,_cust_ordid, cust_addr, cust_phone

I want to grab all this info in a text file or a pdf file,can this be possible using PHP or i need to use shell script.

Help appreciated 
Thanks in advance 
CJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this:

- MySQL's [SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html)
- from the shell: `mysql -u $user -p $dbname -e "SELECT ... FROM $tbl" > out.txt`
- Use PHP or other programming language to query the results, loop through the rows, and output to a file in whatever format you want.

Comment: this would be in a single file but i need to it like this,single file for single record ?

Comment: That is not what you asked for; what is it you actually want? How do you want the files organized? We can't read your mind; please update your question with what you want, and then let me know and I'll update my answer.

Comment: ok here is what i am looking for exactly i will have the customer database as explained earlier with same table now if there are 100 records in the table. my front end will have a button to export data from the table when it is pressed all the records will not be in a single file but each record will have its own file with the data in it say for example the table has cust_id => 1 ,cust_name => john doe, cust_phone => 000-000-0000,cust_addr => some addr.       now when i hit the export button file with cust_name will be created with all the data in the text file, let me know if this is clear

Comment: use a loop and write each line into a different file.  For example, in PHP: `$n = 0; while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)){ file_put_contents('myfile_row_'.($n++),$row); }`

Comment: got it cegfault done really appreciate your response,